# Git "No such repository"

Tags: git

I am a kind of new user to git and there still several things not clear for me after extensive usage of svn.

Here is my problem:

I have repo on xp dev: ssh://xp-dev.com/my_repo_name

it contains two branches master and dev, as you can see I have local and remote branches

```
git branch -a
* dev
  master
  remotes/origin/dev
  remotes/origin/master

git remote -v
origin  ssh://xp-dev.com/my_repo_name (fetch)
origin  ssh://xp-dev.com/my_repo_name (push)
```

but when I try to push committed changes to "dev" branch it says:

```
git push
No such repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Please help me to understand what is wrong.

**UPDATE#1**

```
git remote show origin
No such repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

**UPDATE#2**

```
git push origin cyber_dev
No such repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Comment: What does `git remote show origin` show?

Comment: I've added UPDATE#1 please take a look

Comment: Try answer by @panos2point0 - it may be that you are pushing to a somewhat non-existent branch, or try at server repeating a command in a repo root: `git update-server-info`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
git push origin dev
```

If this works, then there is a problem with your git configuration.

Also make sure you still have access to the repo (valid ssh key or correct password).

Update:

It is starting to look like you no longer have access to the repo.

Try cloning the project to a new folder.

If that doesn't work as well make sure your ssh key is in order.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all your contribution, it helped me to figure out the issue, I've noticed that the name of repository was changed a little and I was not aware about this. I changed it and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to wrong/old passwords stored in your system.
Open Control Panel from the Start menu 
Select User Accounts 
Select "Manage your credentials" in the left hand menu 
Edit your credentials related to Git or GitHub